# Add a class in parent element based on value on child - angular2

Tags: angular

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" [ngClass]="{megaMenu:??? }"> -- first ul
  <li class="dropdown-menuItems" *ngFor="let submenu of menuItems.ChildItems">
    <a>{{submenu.MenuName}}</a>
    <ul *ngIf="submenu.ChildItems.length > 0" class="subDropDown"> ---here if submenu.ChildItems.length > 0, want to add "megaMenu" class to ul(first ul) 
        <li *ngFor="let subChild of submenu.ChildItems">
            <a href="#">{{subChild.MenuName}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to check the value in *ngIf in second ul, see if the length value is greater than 0, if yes, then add "megaMenu" class to the top ul.

Comment: What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: Added a boolean property "megaMenuTrigger" in component, added 
[(ngModel)]="megaMenuTrigger= (submenu.ChildItems.length > 0) ? true : false"  in second ul, thought if the value megaMenuTrigger changed, will add the styling class in the top ul. But it back fired.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider explicitly assigning `megaMenu` value by calling code inside component.

```
megaMenuVisible = menuItems.ChildItems
.map((item) => item.ChildItems.length)
.filter(i=> i).length;
```

**Html**

```
[ngClass]="{megaMenu: megaMenuVisible }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Used a boolean property "needMegaMenu" in component.ts. 
In the "for" iteration where I'm converting my Json into model, if submenu has children, I made the boolean to true.
From then on, the task was easy, [ngClass]="{megaMenu: needMegaMenu}".

But I would still like to know if my the approach where in one can observe the value somewhere and change the [ngClass] based on that condition.
Hopefully element reference should work, #subMenuUl and use that in the top ul.